# Using ACL_CONNECTED and ACL_DISCONNECTED for bluetooth doesn't seem to work on Android 4.2.2. Any Solution?

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I've been using a receiver to monitor those intents for a while now to monitor an active bluetooth connection. I've found now that on my Galaxy S4 running android 4.2.2, these intents do not seem to take at all.

It works on my Transformer Infinity(4.1), Droid Bionic(4.1), and Droid X(2.3.3). Was something changed in 4.2.2 that breaks this method?

Heres my code for reference.

```
public class BluetoothReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    public static boolean BluetoothConnected;

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {

        Log.d(TAG, "Bluetooth Intent Recieved");

        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.d(TAG, "Bluetooth Called: Action: " + action);

        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED"))
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "BLUETOOTH CONNECTED RECIEVED");
            BluetoothConnected = true;
        }

        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED"))
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "BLUETOOTH DISCONNECTED RECIEVED");
            BluetoothConnected = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

the issue is, you have to remove these  `android:enabled="true"` and `android:exported="false"` from your **BroadcastReceiver**.

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.BluetoothReceiver " 
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED" />
                <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED" />
                <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

change this into this:

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.BluetoothReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED" />
                <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_DISCONNECTED" />
                <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: I was skeptical seeing that this answer had been downvoted, but it actually works! To be precise: android:exported has to be set to true. True is the default value and that's why removing works as well.